# Android Studio - Windows 7 - Sony Z3 Compact - Device doesn't appear

Tags: windows, android-studio, sony

I saw a lot of post on the subject, tried to figure it out but it seems I miss something :(

My config : Windows 7 64 bits
My Phone : Sony Z3 compact (Android version 6.0.1)

- The phone is automatically detected by Windows
- The phone is on USB debug mode
- The config USB is set on MTP (tried changed it too with no effect)
- No warning or error in the windows manager device. The phone appears ok and updated.
- Delete my smartphone driver - Reinstall them (automatically or by the oem driver found on the website)
- Changed USB cable (the official and others)
- Project configure to run the minimal version of SDK 4.0.3
- In Android Studio > Tools > Android SDK 
   => Android SDK 7.0 (Nougat) was Installed by default
   => Installed Android SDK 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)
   => Installed Android SDK 6.0 (Marshmallow)
   => Installed Google USB Driver
- In Android Studio > File > Project Structure
   => Tried to change the compiled  SDK Version positionned on Android 7.0 by default in 6.0 and then 4.0.3 with no effect
- In Android Studio, Install
- In Android Studio, Target is set on "Open select Deployement Target Plateforme". Tried to choose directly the USB device with no effect (no target device found)

Try this too :

Go to your sdk tool installation path, and under \sdk\platform-tools folder and run this command:

C:\android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
=> Blank list as a result

adb kill-server => Ok

adb start-server => OK

Thank your for any help you can provide

Jerome

Comment: I said "Hi all" in the begining of my message :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today's operation :

- changed the USB port (no effect)
- revoked all the debug's authorization in the developer's options
- put the USB configuration on PTP Mode (didn't appear before but with no effect)
- put the USB configurtion on RNDIS (USB Ethernet) (didn't appear before) 
  => Windows tried to download drivers (?). Failed on one step. My device appeared then in warning in manager device. Install the manually oem driver download the first time. Then my phone asked me too authorized my computer to use the debug mode. 
  Said yes and now it works.

Hope it can help someone.